# The underlying provider failed on Open in azure app services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework, azure-web-app-service

I have Entity framework DB first app deployed in Azure app services. My DB is located in a separate VM. Im getting above exception when app try to access the database. Do i need to do IPs white list, fire wall change or any kind of access allowing to get data from the DB?

With the same connection, local host is working fine.

this is my fake credential connection string from app service configurations

```
metadata=res://\*/Model.csdl|res://\*/Model.ssdl|res://\*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data source=11.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=fakeUser;Password=1234567890;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried with only "Data source=11.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=fakeUser;Password=1234567890;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"

Comment: That's connection string for code-first.  And is your VM accessible over a Public IP?  Can you connect from your desktop?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  yes. i can connect to VM from desktop